# Move to target with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I am trying to move my camera to a clicked Gameobjects position with a specified offset. So the script should calculate the resulting position by the clicked gameobjects position, the actual camera position and a offset.

I have tried it with this code:

```
Vector3 distanceVector = transform.position - target.transform.position;
Vector3 distanceVectorNormalized = distanceVector.normalized;
targetPosition = (distanceVectorNormalized * preferredDistance);
```

But I am getting some really weird values. Here is the code I made for this:

```
public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;

private bool moving = false;
private GameObject target;

// The distance between the camera and the targets position
private float preferredDistance = 3;

// The position the camera will move to
private Vector3 targetPosition;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 100) == false) return;

        Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
        target = hit.transform.gameObject;

        ... Here should be the calculations

        moving = true;
    }

    if (moving)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed);
        transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);

        var offsetX = Math.Abs(transform.position.x - targetPosition.x);
        var offsetZ = Math.Abs(transform.position.z - targetPosition.z);

        if (offsetX < .01
            && offsetZ < .01) moving = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normalized `distanceVector` acts as the direction of the camera to the object.
This direction should be normalized, which you do, so it can be multiplied by your `preferredDistance`. It then becomes the offset of the camera from the target.

The part where it goes wrong is that you set this *normalized* offset as the new camera position, while it should be added to it:

```
Vector3 distanceVector = transform.position - target.transform.position;
Vector3 distanceVectorNormalized = distanceVector.normalized;
targetPosition = target.transform.position + (distanceVectorNormalized * preferredDistance);
```

Note the difference in the last line.